# Using int variable when declaring array size

Tags: c#, arrays

I am quite new to c#, and still don't understand some basics about arrays. When I initialize my program, I ask the user for an input, in integer form, and then I use that to declare the size of the array. 
Implementation:

```
int sortSpaceSize = Console.Read ();
bool[] sortSpace = new bool[sortSpaceSize];
```

However, when I test the program, the array size is just...wierd. When I type 45 as an input, it outputs an array size of 52. With 964684, it outputs 57. I have no idea on what is wrong. If you are not allowed to use variables as sizes when declaring arrays, then why does this not throw an error? Should I use a list instead? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Should I use a list instead?` That's not the cause of your error, but you almost certainly should, yes.

Comment: `Console.Read();` only reads one character. Change `Console.Read();` to `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine();)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are only reading one char. Try reading a complete number:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int sortSpaceSize;
if (!Int32.TryParse(input, out sortSpaceSize))
{
    throw new Exception("not a number");
}
bool[] sortSpace = new bool[sortSpaceSize];
```

As Chris made it clear why you get those strange numbers: you are converting the [`ascii code`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) of the first digit and used that as your array size.

Comment: Yup. And to clarify with 45 as an input the array size is 52 which is the ascii code for `4`. Likewise 57 is the ascii code for `9`, the first character of 964684.

Comment: As a comment on code it is probably worth either checking the return of `TryParse` if you think it might fail or if you don't expect it to fail just use `Int.Parse`. If you use `TryParse` and then throw away the success you may end up hiding errors (eg if the person types "blah" instead of a number then `sortSpaceSize` will probably end up as 0.